# PayPal Checkout without Details and Subtotal

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I use the PayPal SDK for PHP and want to go to the checkout without showing details and total instead of subtotal (like on the picture left).
Thanks!

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdpls.png)

This is the Code i use.

```
$arrPrices = $this->getPrices();

$apiContext = $this->getApiContext();

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$arrItems = [];

$item = new \PayPal\Api\Item();

$item->setName($saveValues['title'])->setCurrency('EUR')->setQuantity(1)->setPrice($arrPrices['raw']);

$arrItems[] = $item;

$itemList = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();
$itemList->setItems($arrItems);

$details = new \PayPal\Api\Details();
$details->setTax($arrPrices['tax'])->setSubtotal($arrPrices['raw']);

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("EUR")->setTotal($arrPrices['total'])->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)->setItemList($itemList)->setDescription("Vielen Dank für Deine Buchung & bis bald!");

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();

$url = \Environment::get('url') . '/' . $GLOBALS['SCRIPT_URL'];
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$url?success=true")->setCancelUrl("$url?success=false");

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")->setPayer($payer)->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)->addTransaction($transaction);

try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
}
catch (\Exception $ex) {
    return $ex->getData();
}

return $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide the details you will not see the details ? there isn't a way by which you will provide the details and then not have display it on the paypal approval page (of which you are showing the screen shot)